# Python - Highest with alphabetical order from text file

Tags: python

I have made a quiz using python, the end score is out of 10. From this quiz each users name, class and score is saved in a text file. Now what I am trying to do is create a new program which can organize the users name in alphabetical order with the users highest score only and print this out. So far I have been successful in organizing the users name in alphabetical order. 
This is what my code looks like so far

```
def alpha():
  b = open("Class X.txt" , "r")
  fo = b.readlines()
  for x in sorted (fo): 
      print(x)
def beta():
  b = open("Class Y.txt" , "r")
  fo = b.readlines()
  for x in sorted(fo):
      print(x)
def charlie():
  b = open("Class Z.txt" , "r")
  fo = b.readlines()
  for x in sorted(fo):
      print(x)

if option == "A":
  if Class == "X":
    alpha()

  elif Class == "Y":
    beta()

  elif Class == "Z":
    charlie()`
```

What I have been trying to do is print all the users names in alphabetical order from a text file from the desired class, which I have been successful with. However, I have been having great trouble in trying to print the highest score of each user along side their name instead of any of their scores.

Each students name and score is saves like this (Nakita:0) and each text file is saved under three classes, X, Y and Z.

I was wondering whether anyone could help me figure out how to include just the highest score with the users name in alphabetical order like I have done, from the textfile which has been set out like how it it shown above. I have also used the version Python 3.3.2.

Comment: So, each student is in three classes, producing a list of the same names for each printout, with different scores attached? And you want a single list with each student and the highest of their three scores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would probably use a `defaultdict` using student names as keys and the value being a list of their scores. `defaultdict` simply initializes on first access, in this case with an empty list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

scores = defaultdict(list)
```

Next you can condense your script by creating a list of filenames to process and then use that as your outer loop so you don't have to repeat yourself a bunch:

```
def alpha():
  b = open("Class X.txt" , "r")
  fo = b.readlines()
  for x in sorted (fo): 
      print(x)
def beta():
  b = open("Class Y.txt" , "r")
  fo = b.readlines()
  for x in sorted(fo):
      print(x)
def charlie():
  b = open("Class Z.txt" , "r")
  fo = b.readlines()
  for x in sorted(fo):
      print(x)
```

Turns into:

```
class_filenames = ['Class X.txt', 'Class Y.txt', 'Class Z.txt']

for class_file in class_filenames:
    with open(class_file, 'r') as f:
        ...
```

Finally for the body of the loop we need to split each line into names and scores (as integers) and add them to the correct entry, this is easily done with:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    student, score = line.split(':')
    scores[student].append(int(score))
```

Then we can print each name alphabetically by sorting the final dict with the `sorted` iterator and print the `max` of the scorelist for each student:

```
for student, scorelist in sorted(scores.items()):
    print("%s : %d" % (student, max(scorelist)))
```

All together now:

```
from collections import defaultdict

scores = defaultdict(list)

class_filenames = ['Class X.txt', 'Class Y.txt', 'Class Z.txt']

for class_file in class_filenames:
    with open(class_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            student, score = line.split(':')
            scores[student].append(int(score))

for student, scorelist in sorted(scores.items()):
    print("%s : %d" % (student, max(scorelist)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 files with the same names, the code can be like that:

```
lstX = []
lstY = []
lstZ = []
b = open("Class X.txt" , "r")
lstX = b.read().split('\n')
lstX.sort()
b.close()
b = open("Class Y.txt" , "r")
lstY = b.read().split('\n')
lstY.sort()
b.close()
b = open("Class Z.txt" , "r")
lstZ = b.read().split('\n')
lstZ.sort()
b.close()

lst = []
lst.append(lstX)
lst.append(lstY)
lst.append(lstZ)

res = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for q in range(len(lst[i])):
        res.append(int(lst[q][i].split(':')[1]))
    print("%s max. = %s" % (lst[q][i].split(':')[0], max(res)))
    res = []
```

NB: for this code the text files must not have a new line after the last record!
For example, the file "Class X.txt" looked this way:

```
Nakita:0
Makita:1
Zakita:7
```